# Is Terraform Destroying Manually created resources?

Tags: terraform

I have created some resources in Azure using Terraform such as VNETS, VMs, NSGs etc. Let's assume if I create another VM in the same VNET which was created by Terraform, I want to know if I rerun the Terraform script, will the manually created VM gets destroyed since the manually created VM is not in the state file?

Answer (score 1):

No, Terraform does not interfere with resources that are created outside of terraform. It only manages resources that are included in its state file.
However, if you make manual changes to resources that you created through terraform(for example VNET in your case), terraform would reset them to what is declared in terraform code on the next run/execution.